Embeddings Into Groups with Prescribed Automorphisms
If $G$ is a finite group, then we can embed $i : G \hookrightarrow S_n$ for some $n$. WLOG, we may assume that $n > 6$, so that $\mathrm{Out}(S_n) = 0$. This embeds $G$ as a subgroup of a group with no outer automorphisms, however it is very crude in the sense that $S_n$ has far more automorphisms than $G$.
If $G$ is a finite and centerless, then we can embed $G \hookrightarrow G_i$ by mapping repeatedly through inner automorphisms where $G_0 = G, G_{i+1} = \mathrm{Aut}(G_i)$. Wielandt's tower theorem then says that $G_i$ eventually stabilize, i.e. there is some $n$ such that $G_{n+1} = G_n$, e.g. all automorphisms of $G_n$ are inner, so $\mathrm{Out}(G_n) = 0$.
Both of these methods do not necessarily kill outer automorphisms of $G$, however doing so with a group like the holomorph can add extra outer automorphisms, e.g. $\mathrm{Hol}(S_3)$. Additionally, this turns outer automorphisms into inner automorphisms, it does not get rid of them.
Is there a way to get the best of all of these? For any group $G$, does there exist a group $H$ with $\mathrm{Out}(H) = 0$ and $G \hookrightarrow H$ embedded as a normal, and hence characteristic, subgroup of $H$ such that $\mathrm{Aut}(H) \to \mathrm{Aut}(G)$ given by restriction is an isomorphism onto $\mathrm{Inn}(G)$?

You write $\text{Aut}(H) \to \text{Inn}(G)$ in your closing question as if there were some definition of some such homomorphism. If that was your intention, I do not see how that homomorphism is defined. I see how $\text{Aut}(H) \to \text{Aut}(G)$ is defined, but I don't see any reason why the image is contained in $\text{Inn}(G)$.

@LeeMosher Sorry, that is my bad. I rewrote the last part of the question a couple of times and this slipped through that. I have now editted the question so that it is what I am actually interested in.

How can it be an isomorphism? Isn't $G\le H$ already mapping onto $Inn(G)$?

@SteveD I am not sure what you mean. The map $\mathrm{Aut}(H) \to \mathrm{Aut}(G)$ is given by taking an automorphism $\phi : H \to H$ and restricting it to $G$, i.e. $\phi \mapsto \phi|_G$. This maps into $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ since $G$ is characteristic in $H$. The question is then if you can get this map to be an isomorphism onto $\mathrm{Inn}(G)$. Equivalently, this is asking if you can find a group $H$ whose automorphisms are given uniquely by extension of an inner automorphism on the subgroup $G$.

Sorry I thought you meant $H$ was centerless. Ok so you're looking for a group $H=GZ(H)$ that has no outer automorphisms. So if $G$ is centerless itself, then $H$ would be $G\times A$ for an Abelian group $G$, so $|A|\le2$.

@SteveD The actual group that I am interested in is when $G$ is the Heisenberg group with integral coefficients. That is not centerless. But it seems that if $G$ is centerless, then as you said, $H = G \times A$ with $A = 0$ or $A = \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. So the existence of H would require conditions on $G$.

"as a normal, and hence characteristic, subgroup"... I think you mean it the other way around: if it is characteristic then it is normal, but being a normal subgroup in no way entails being characteristic!

Is there any example at all of a group $G$ with outer automorphisms for which such a group $H$ exists?
